# Is a verification step needed for Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

With Google Analytics there used to be a "Verification" step which involved placing a verification file in your server root dir or adding a DNS entry. Is this needed for Universal Analytics?

I've just added a new UA account and I was given a tracking code right away.. nothing was said about verification. I've checked the upgrade docs and as far as I can tell there is no mention of a verification step.

If someone knows the answer it will save me some time with setting up a test analytics site and waiting for it to start tracking!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verification step is for Google webmaster tools. It was never necessary for GA (to use GA you must be able to place code in the page in the first place, so further verification is not necessary).